# Retrieving Items from DIV - JS

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am able to fetch data from database and append to my `panel` as in my code. But the problem is on page load for instance,

This is what happens

```
name   cost   sub-total  qty  pts
Books  12.00      120    10    2

Pencil 5.00       120     2    2
```

What i expect

```
   name   cost   sub-total  qty  pts
    Books  12.00      120    10   2

    Pencil 5.00       10     2    2
```

What happens is, the subtotal for the first item shows the same for the second item and this only happens when i include `Function()` in the document load function.   I don't seem to know why this is happening ?

**PS:  Sorry for my bad english that is why i try to explain using examples**

```
<script>
$( document ).ready(function() {

    @foreach ($grades->grade as $mark)
        var item = $('#{!! $mark->id !!}');    
    var ad = JSON.parse(item.attr('data-grade'));
    if(item.prop("checked") )  {
        $('.panel').append(
            '<div class="container"> '+ 

    '<p>  class="name" >'+ad.name+'</td>'+
    '<p  class="price" data-price="'+ad.price+'">'+ad.price+'</p>'+
    '<p class="total" ><span class="line-total" name="total" id="total"></span></p>'+
    '<input  type="text" class="form-control quantity"  placeholder=" qty " name="quantity[]" value="{!!$deliver->pivot->quantity!!}" required/>'+
    '<p class="pts-total" ><span class="point-total" name="pts-total" id="pts-total"></span></p>'+    
    '</div>'
            )
    }
    else {

        });
    }     }

    Function();

       @endforeach


});
</script>


<script>
var sum;
var total_points;
var Function = function() {


  var container = $('.panel').closest('div');

        var quantity = Number($('.quantity').val());
        var price = Number($('.panel').closest('div').find('.price').data('price'));    
       var points = Number($('.panel').closest('div').find('.points').data('points'));  

       container.find(".total span").text(quantity * price);
       container.find(".pts-total span").text(quantity * points);

        sum = 0;
       total_points = 0;

       $(".line-total").each(function(){
       sum = sum + quantity*price;
       })   


       $(".pts-total").each(function(){
       total_points = total_points + quantity*points;
       })    

       }
</script>
```

Comment: Did you check your JSON if it actually returns correct value? and give the function a clear name of what it does rather than common name as function.

Comment: @NareshKumar  When i take out the `Function()`, it don't face this issue but when i include it, that is when i get this error.. .I think i am not getting the right selector perhaps

Comment: yes you are using the same selector for quantity and price. add while appending to div use some integer along with the name and get read it in the function you can solve it by then

Comment: @NareshKumar i don't understand your statement please. Can you produce an answer to make me understand much better